# Quantity for over night oats

Tags: oats

I cook Quaker Oats overnight and love it but sometimes the pre-measured packets make too too little food. I am interested in making my own servings using cups, but do not know what proportions I should use. For example, I heard on YouTube that 2 cups of oats per 1 cup of milk/water.

What is the best ratio of oats to liquid to prepare oats overnight?

Answer (score 5):

Weigh the contents of one packet.
Check the packet instructions to see how much liquid to add.

That's your ratio, very precisely.

You can then apply that ratio to any measurement.

Answer (score 1):

This is close to being a recipe request, if it isn't one.

It depends on how you like your oats. The ratio I've used in the past is 1:1 oats/water + other toppings. 2:1 Oats : water sounds wrong. Oats suck up the liquid, so you want more liquid than oats generally.

There are ample resources online because overnight oats are a huge deal right now, and have been for the past few years. The best thing to do would be to start with 1:1 ratio, then adjust according to how that comes out. Sorry if this isn't a great answer, but there are tons of resources available already. :)

Comment: Rather than saying, "there are tons of resources", it is preferrable for answers to include links that help support your answer and the advice you offer. Like a link to a blog post or foodie article that explains the "how to" and "options" for making overnight oats. The Help Center's page on [How Do I Write a Good Answer?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) offers some great guidelines!

Comment: @elbrant nowhere in our guidelines for answering (which you linked) is any kind of pressure on  people ot provide links to support their statements. We intentionally don't have a "citation needed" rule. Sometimes, when a user sees an answer which states something unexpected and/or intriguing, the user can ask in comments for further reading material, but that's a separate thing from requiring people to start filling their answers with links for the sake of it.

Comment: What would be helpful, however, is how you define 1:1 - by weight or volume? While a reader in the US would probably assume the latter, I from my European perspective tend to read the former. And yes, there is a significant difference, as a cup of oats weights only about 90g.

Comment: And a reminder: while we don’t accept simple recipe requests, the question is about ratios, which is totally fine.

Comment: @Stephie They called out cups specifically in their post, so I just assumed that they would apply that to an otherwise ambiguous answer. I'll keep this advice in mind for  future answers/comments!

Comment: @Stephie And this question is weird since it's asking for a ratio of ingredients, when recipes are really the same thing. There is no real, strong answer; you can make it to taste. But I'm not going to question a moderator, so I'll let it go. :)

Comment: @rumtscho I learned that from others critiquing my own answers, which I assumed they were correct about. As such, I thought saying, "here are tons of resources available ", (i.e.; "look it up"), was specifically a "no-no". Otherwise our database of solutions would become polluted with "google it" answers. Am I wrong about this?

Comment: @elbrant that’s something that should be discussed either informally in our [chat] or would warrant a Meta question. Too complex for a comment discussion, plus that’s not the right place. Feel free to ping rumtscho or me in chat, even though we may be not immediately available.